# How do I find the induced Riemannian metric of a real smooth complete intersection?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

If I have a smooth complete intersection of $f_1,\ldots,f_k \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, presented as the vanishing locus
$$
f_1 = 0 \text{ } \cdots \text{ } f_k = 0
$$
in $\mathbb{R}^n$, how can I find the pullback of the standard euclidean metric under the inclusion map?

---

Consider the 4-manifold $M_1$ given by the vanishing of
$$
\sin^3(x_1) - x_1^2\cdot x_3 + x_2^2 + x_4^3 + x_5^4 + 1
$$

---

Consider the 3-manifold $M_2$ given by the vanishing locus of
$$
\begin{align*}
x_1^2 + x_2^2 - x_3^4 + x_4\cdot x_5 + 1 \\
x_2^2 - x_1\cdot x_3 + x_4^4 + x_4\cdot x_5
\end{align*}
$$
This is indeed a manifold since the jacobian is given by the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2x_1 & 2x_2 & -4x_3^3 & -x_5 & -x_4 \\
-x_3 & 2x_2 & -x_1 & 4x_3^3 + x_5 & x_4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which drops rank only at $(0,0,0,0,0)$

Comment: Do you have a parametrization? If not, how explicitly is your manifold described?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I'm describing my manifold as the vanishing locus of k smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $k < n$.

Comment: I understand that, but without a more explicit description of your manifold it's difficult to imagine what sort of expression you hope to find for the metric. For example, if $k = n - 1$, your manifold is a curve, so the pullback metric is flat, no matter what the $f_{j}$ are. Similarly, multiplying each $f_{j}$ by a non-vanishing function has no effect on the pullback metric. Particularly, a useful differential expression in the $f_{j}$ looks Highly Unlkely.

Comment: This may be too ambitious of a question then. I'll write a couple example manifolds, and see where this goes.

Comment: What sort of description of the metric are you expecting? In terms of what?

Comment: For lack of a better term, in coordinates? For example, I looked at example 2 in the middle of page 3 of http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/graphmetric.pdf

Comment: Here's what I want to be able to do with this: compute the curvature tensor, compute examples of geodesics, find the levi-civita connection and compute characteristic classes with that.

Comment: In Example 2.2 of those notes, there's a graph parametrization: $$(x, y) \mapsto \bigl(x, y, f(x, y)\bigr).$$Passing from a set of implicit hypersurfaces to a parametrization of their intersection is Difficult. Getting from a parametrization to an expression for the pullback metric is Easy. Getting from a coordinate description of a metric to the curvature tensor, and to explicit descriptions of geodesics, is Difficult. ("Difficult" means "effectively impossible in general", and "Easy" means "third-semester calculus".)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for this comment. Should I leave my question on the website for the sake of leaving it online?